# cannot find the declaration of element soap:envelope

Tags: xml, events, soap, postman

```
im trying to send an epcis subscription query in xml through Postman but i get the following error: "cannot find the declaration of element soap:envelope", what could be the problem?
```

this is the body that im sending in postman:

```
it should be correct for the most part, but somehow the declaration is wrong!
i tried many declarations by the way!
```

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:sbdh="http://www.unece.org/cefact/namespaces/StandardBusinessDocumentHeader" xmlns:epcis="urn:epcglobal:epcis:xsd:1">
   <soapenv:Body>
      <epcis:Subscribe>
         <queryName>SimpleEventQuery</queryName>
         <params>
            <param>
               <name>eventType</name>
               <value>ObjectEvent</value>
            </param>
            <param>
               <name>GE_eventTime</name>
               <value>2022-01-01T00:00:00Z</value>
            </param>
         </params>
         <dest>http://user:password@localhost:9090/dest/subscribe</dest>
         <controls>
            <schedule>
               <second>0,30</second>
            </schedule>
            <reportIfEmpty>false</reportIfEmpty>
         </controls>
         <subscriptionID>QueryTCR<n+2>a</subscriptionID>
      </epcis:Subscribe>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>

it should be correct for the most part, but somehow the declaration is wrong!
i tried many declarations by the way!
```

Answer (score 0):

A little bit late, but maybe it can still be helpful:

I can see 2 issues in your request:

- The epcis schema is not correct. It shoud be `urn:epcglobal:epcis-query:xsd:1` and not `urn:epcglobal:epcis:xsd:1`
- The subscription name contains invalid XML characters `<` and `>`. You can escape them to `&lt;` and `&gt;` or put the value in a `<![CDATA[...]]>` XML tag. However I'd recommend to remove them entirely if possible

So a valid request would be:

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"  xmlns:epcis="urn:epcglobal:epcis-query:xsd:1">
   <soapenv:Body>
      <epcis:Subscribe>
         <queryName>SimpleEventQuery</queryName>
         <params>
            <param>
               <name>eventType</name>
               <value>ObjectEvent</value>
            </param>
            <param>
               <name>GE_eventTime</name>
               <value>2022-01-01T00:00:00Z</value>
            </param>
         </params>
         <dest>http://user:password@localhost:9090/dest/subscribe</dest>
         <controls>
            <schedule>
               <second>0,30</second>
            </schedule>
            <reportIfEmpty>false</reportIfEmpty>
         </controls>
         <subscriptionID>QueryTCR</subscriptionID>
      </epcis:Subscribe>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```